# Empty XML on CRM Javascript

Tags: javascript, crm

I would like get the value from another entity, so I can use that for validation. but when I try to debug javascript, XML returned error, and I dont know why. I try to use debugger, and it failed on the `var xHReq = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");`. The first XML on  `var xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>" +` returned right, but when I continue to `var xHReq = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");`, it returned empty. Check this link, hopefully you can help me go through this.. thanks.

http://pastebin.com/jxhU2WgJ

Comment: Yap, its null... well, I checked that already, something weird is line 39 has correct xml, then when it went to line 80, it was null. error messages said "wrong xml or invalid xml, sort of".. I changed the fetchxml already with another pattern, but I am still curious about this syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Think I found the problem. Not sure why your debugging suggested that `xml` was null - I tried it on my system and it was fine (which makes sense - nothing in your code would reset the `xml` variable anyway).

The clue was in the error message: 
`...Instance validation error: \'eq\' is not a valid value for ConditionOperator`

**Resolution**

```
"<q1:Operator>eq</q1:Operator>" +
```

to this:

```
"<q1:Operator>Equal</q1:Operator>" +
```